# Unique solution to ODE even though $f(x,y)$ is not Lipschitz continuous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given an ODE with initial value the Picard-Lindelöf theorem is assuring the existence and uniqueness of a solution. Since the statement is an if-then statement, I would like to have an example of an ODE where the solution is unique even though the function $f(x,y)$ is not Lipschitz continuous on the second variable or eventually not continuous on the first variable. Do you know of such an example ? Thanks.

Comment: How about $f(x, y) = \lfloor x \rfloor$?

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit or write an answer ? Thanks.